# BigQuery: unnesting timestamp intervals by values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

I have a BigQuery table `data`:

```
value    minute    pre_minute
AAA      25        24
AAB      04        03
AAC      04        03
...
ZZY      00        59
ZZZ      12        11
```

where all columns store STRING values. `minute` contains a random minute from `"00"` to `"29"`, where `pre_minute` is one minute less than the `minute` column, with an exception of when `minute = "00"`, in which the corresponding `pre_minute` is `"59"`.

I would like to create 30-minute time intervals for each `value` throughout 24 hours, with each starting minute of `value` being its `minute`. For example, I would make 48 intervals for `AAA` starting from `"00:25:00"` to `"00:24:59"` the next date.

Creating the intervals for a single `value` is simple. For `value = "AAA"`:

```
  SELECT TIME(time_interval) AS start_time,
         TIME(TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_ADD(time_interval, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)) AS end_time
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE() - 1, " 00:25:00 UTC")), TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), " 00:24:59 UTC")), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)) time_interval
```

However, I can't seem to put the `value` aspect in if I use `UNNEST()`.

I tried using `CASE WHEN ...` :

```
SELECT value,
       TIME(time_interval) AS start_time,
       TIME(TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP_ADD(time_interval, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)) AS end_time
  FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN minute != "00" THEN UNNEST(...)
           ...
          FROM data)
```

which was unsuccessful.

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would like to create 30-minute time intervals `for each` value throughout 24 hours, the `CROSS JOIN` could be called with each variable of the value.

Below is the extension of the code that you provided.

#### Query

```
WITH
dataset AS (
    SELECT 'AAA' as value, '25' as minute, '24' as pre_minute,
    UNION ALL SELECT 'AAB', '04', '03',
    UNION ALL SELECT 'AAC', '04', '03',
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ZZY', '00', '59',
    UNION ALL SELECT 'ZZZ', '12', '11',
),
value_time_interval AS (
    SELECT
        value,
        TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE() - 1, FORMAT(" 00:%s:00 UTC", minute))) as start_dt,  -- use %02d if INT64
        TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), FORMAT(" 00:%s:59 UTC", pre_minute))) as end_dt,
    FROM dataset
)
SELECT value, start_dt, end_dt, time_interval
FROM value_time_interval
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
    GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
        start_dt, end_dt, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
    )
) as time_interval
ORDER BY value, start_dt, end_dt, time_interval
;
```

#### Results

[image]